# Mnesia folder not created for one of the node in the cluster

Tags: ansible, rabbitmq

While trying to start rabbitmq, I get below error and I observe that /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia directory exist for host 1 and 2 but not in 3:

```
fatal: [host-3]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["rabbitmqctl", "cluster_status"], "delta": "0:00:00.986969", "end": "2019-08-14 15:04:09.714266", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2019-08-14 15:04:08.727297", "stderr": "Error: {aborted,{bad_config,dir,\n                            \"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@host-3\"}}", "stderr_lines": ["Error: {aborted,{bad_config,dir,", "                            \"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@host-3\"}}"], "stdout": "Cluster status of node 'rabbit@host-3' ...", "stdout_lines": ["Cluster status of node 'rabbit@host-3' ..."]}
```

```
- name: Check RabbitMQ cluster
  command: rabbitmqctl cluster_status
  register: result
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the generated configuration for RabbitMQ has a syntax error, resulting in a lot of whitespace for the mnesia directory value:

```
bad_config,dir,\n                            \"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@host-3\"
```

I would double-check the configuration input, and also check the generated configuration files in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.../config/generated/rabbitmq.config`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I verified /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config and see below contents: ```[{rabbit,
[
{loopback_users, []},
{cluster_nodes, {['host-1', 'host-2', 'host-3'], disc}},
{cluster_partition_handling,pause_minority},
{default_user, <<"user">>},
{default_pass, <<"password">>},
{kernel, [{net_ticktime,  30}]}
]}].```

Comment: `cluster_nodes` names should be `rabbit@host-1`, `rabbit@host-2`, etc. Otherwise that looks fine. I'm not sure what is causing your error.